# Should I code in TableViewCell or ViewController? for expandability/flexibility

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Now I have `TableView` on `UIViewController`, and I allocate `MapView` on `CustomTableViewCell`.

From the point of view of `MVC`, I think that all processing systems should be written in `UIViewController`.
I tried to write `MapView's` processing to `UIViewController`,
But, I don't know whether to write to `CustomTableViewCell` or `UIViewController`.

We plan to place multiple `CustomTableViewCells` in `TableView` of `UITViewController`, I think that `UIViewController` will become enlarged.

What kind of method is best for keeping state with high expandability/flexibility?

Comment: MVC is not suitable for iOS. Since ViewController acts as a View due to tight coupling of VC with View. Use "MVP" or "Swift Clean Arch.".

Comment: thank you for quick comment, I google MVP, Swift Clean Arch

Comment: MVVM is also a good option as the codes will be shifted to view-model.

Comment: See for yourself. I am sure you'll have an answer after reading this - https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52